# Rabin cryptosystem - How many solutions?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, residue-calculus, cryptography, quadratic-residues

If in [Rabin cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem) we have $n = p \cdot q$ where $p$ and $q$ is prime we have four solutions (roots) - exist four solution of $x^2 \equiv b \pmod{n}$.

However, when we have:

$n = p \cdot q \cdot r$

where $p$ and $q$ and $r$ is prime or:

$n = p \cdot q \cdot r \cdot z$

where $p$ and $q$ and $r$ and $z$ is prime

How much will we have solutions?

will they be $2^k$? where $k$ is the number of prime numbers?